# Make jest + nock + axios + typescript work after upgrading axios from 0.28 to 1.5

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs, nock

I've been working with Axios to get content from Dynamic Yield.
We were working with axios 0.28.
Everything was working in frontend.
We also had tests in typescript (jest + nock) that worked.
But we've upgraded axios to latest (1.5) version.
And now tests don't work any more.

I think that the problem is with the OPTIONS preflight request.

I've tried to cope with that, by intercepting OPTIONS request (before real POST request).
But it doesn't work, whatever I try.

The tests look like this:

```
import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
import nock from 'nock';
import type { Config } from './dependency-injection/config';
import type { ChooseApiRequest } from './api/contract/choose/ChooseApiRequest';
import type { Choice, ChooseApiResponse } from './api/contract/choose/ChooseApiResponse';
import { dy } from './services';

const API_KEY = '6394b44ef96243bf8e6e2aad7f59d389';
const CHOOSE_API_URL = 'https://direct.dy-api.eu/v2/serve/user/choose';

window.dynamicYieldConfig = {
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    chooseEndpointUrl: CHOOSE_API_URL,
} satisfies Config;

describe('Dynamic Yield: services.dy - the DynamicYield facade', () => {
    const CURRENT_URL = 'https://shop.de/';

    const server = nock('https://direct.dy-api.eu:443/')
        .matchHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .matchHeader('DY-API-KEY', API_KEY);

    it('should provide an abstraction over the `choose` endpoint (independent from cookies)', async () => {
        // nock.disableNetConnect();

        const CAMPAIGN_NAME = 'campaign';

        // given
        window.pageType = 'Home';
        window.location.assign(CURRENT_URL);

        const expectedRequest: ChooseApiRequest = {
            context: {
                page: {
                    type: 'HOMEPAGE',
                    data: [],
                    location: CURRENT_URL,
                },
            },
            selector: { names: [CAMPAIGN_NAME] },
            options: { isImplicitImpressionMode: true },
        };

        const choiceReturnedByServer: Choice = {
            id: 9999,
            name: CAMPAIGN_NAME,
            type: 'DECISION',
            decisionId: 'decision-id',
            variations: [
                {
                    id: 8888,
                    payload: {
                        type: 'CUSTOM_JSON',
                        data: { 'custom-key': 'custom-value' },
                    },
                },
            ],
        };

        server
            .persist()
            .intercept('/v2/serve/user/choose', 'OPTIONS').reply(204, '', {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application:json"
        })
            // @ts-ignore
            .post('/v2/serve/user/choose', expectedRequest)
            .reply(200, {
                choices: [choiceReturnedByServer],
                cookies: [
                    {
                        name: '_dyjsession',
                        value: 'new-session-id-from-server',
                        maxAge: '3600',
                    },
                ],
                warnings: [],
            } satisfies ChooseApiResponse);

        await expect(
            (async () => {
                // when
                const result = await dy().choose({
                    selector: { names: [CAMPAIGN_NAME] },
                    options: { isImplicitImpressionMode: true },
                });

                // then
                expect(result.get('DECISION', CAMPAIGN_NAME)).toEqual(choiceReturnedByServer);
            })(),
        ).resolves.not.toThrowError();

        // without consent, DY shall not have session persistence with cookies
        expect(document.cookie).not.toContain('_dyjsession');
    });

   
});
```

Of course the expected result is for nock to mock the response and return the values defined in test.

When I'm using `nock.recorder.rec()` I'm getting following logs:

```
  console.log
    
    <<<<<<-- cut here -->>>>>>
    {
      "scope": "https://direct.dy-api.eu:443",
      "method": "OPTIONS",
      "path": "/v2/serve/user/choose",
      "body": "",
      "status": 204,
      "response": "",
      "rawHeaders": [
        "Server",
        "DynamicYieldAPI/2.0",
        "Date",
        "Tue, 05 Sep 2023 10:17:36 GMT",
        "Content-Length",
        "0",
        "Connection",
        "keep-alive",
        "Expires",
        "Tue, 05 Sep 2023 11:17:36 GMT",
        "Cache-Control",
        "max-age=3600",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "http://localhost",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
        "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "DY-API-Key, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Authorization, Postman-Token, DY-Explain",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age",
        "1728000",
        "Allow",
        "POST,OPTIONS",
        "Vary",
        "Origin",
        "DY-Trace-ID",
        "25a4ebc36407952cdce0b83ad0e8d910",
        "P3P",
        "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"NOI DSP COR NID CUR ADM DEV OUR BUS\"",
        "Content-Type",
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      ],
      "reqheaders": {
        "referer": "http://localhost/",
        "origin": "http://localhost",
        "access-control-request-method": "POST",
        "access-control-request-headers": "DY-API-KEY",
        "host": "direct.dy-api.eu"
      },
      "responseIsBinary": false
    }
    <<<<<<-- cut here -->>>>>>

      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/nock/lib/recorder.js:280:13)

  console.log
    
    <<<<<<-- cut here -->>>>>>
    {
      "scope": "https://direct.dy-api.eu:443",
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/v2/serve/user/choose",
      "body": {
        "context": {
          "page": {
            "type": "HOMEPAGE",
            "data": [],
            "location": "https://shop.de/"
          }
        },
        "selector": {
          "names": [
            "campaign"
          ]
        },
        "options": {
          "isImplicitImpressionMode": true
        }
      },
      "status": 401,
      "response": {
        "error": 401
      },
      "rawHeaders": [
        "Server",
        "DynamicYieldAPI/2.0",
        "Date",
        "Tue, 05 Sep 2023 10:17:36 GMT",
        "Transfer-Encoding",
        "chunked",
        "Connection",
        "keep-alive",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "http://localhost",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
        "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "DY-API-Key, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Authorization, Postman-Token, DY-Explain",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age",
        "1728000",
        "Allow",
        "POST,OPTIONS",
        "DY-Trace-ID",
        "2e6eea7fe13ace0dd81abeaa565b4bd5",
        "P3P",
        "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"NOI DSP COR NID CUR ADM DEV OUR BUS\"",
        "Content-Type",
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      ],
      "reqheaders": {
        "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "dy-api-key": "6394b44ef96243bf8e6e2aad7f59d389",
        "referer": "http://localhost/",
        "accept-language": "en",
        "origin": "http://localhost",
        "content-length": 158,
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "host": "direct.dy-api.eu"
      },
      "responseIsBinary": false
    }
    <<<<<<-- cut here -->>>>>>

      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/nock/lib/recorder.js:280:13)


Error: expect(received).resolves.not.toThrowError()

Received promise rejected instead of resolved
Rejected to value: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]
```

I'd say that the OPTIONS preflight request isn't intercepted ... but if I knew what's the problem I wouldn't be here right? :p